# displaying Active Directory high-res user photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory, thumbnails

I want to display a user's high-res photo that they uploaded in Active Directory.

You can access this photo AFTER authentication by visiting the direct URL (changed for privacy):

https://exchange.mycompany.org/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=name@mycompany.org&size=HR648x648

So, this works after authentication:

```
<img alt="UserPhoto" src='https://exchange.mycompany.org/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=name@mycompany.org&size=HR648x648'/>
```

I totally understand why you'd want this to be behind authentication but is there a way to access this without authenticating?

I also tried download the photos through curl, so I could potentially upload them to my database: (no luck)

```
curl -u DOMAIN\\username:password -O https://exchange.mycompany.org/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=name@mycompany.org&size=HR648x648
```

Anyone have a creative solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run a ruby script to authenticate on the backend using:

```
system('curl -u username:password -o filename.jpeg url_of_photo')
```

This downloaded the photos locally. Then they can be viewed without authentication.